# Android Google Map v2 нарисовать маршрут

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, android-fragment, google-maps

У меня есть Google Map fragment:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="my.package.MapsActivity"
            android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"/>
```

Мое местоположение получаю вот так:

```
private void getMyLocation() {
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16);
    mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

Нужно показать маршрут к заданным координатам, как на фото:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помогла данная [библиотека](https://github.com/tato469/Android/tree/master/routes%20googleMaps%20v2). Мой код:

```
Route supportRoute = new Route();

LatLng source = new LatLng(mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude());
LatLng dest= new LatLng(destLat, destLog);

                supportRoute.drawRoute(mMap, MapsActivity.this, source, dest, true, "en");
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант использовать библиотеку
[Google-Directions-Android](https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android)